# Export artwork with Pantone from Illustrator file to PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pantone

I have an artwork with one Pantone colour and I need to export it to PDF with Press Quality. In "Save Adobe PDF" window in section "Output" is it correct to choose "No conversion" in order to export it with correct Pantone colour information?

Comment: Just save as PDF and choose PDF/X-1a... everything will be correct (including spots) for commercial presses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my experience when I export a PDF and choose press quality illustrator keeps colours as pantones if they were set as such.

This is what the output looks like when I export my artwork
[image: 1]]

When I re-open the PDF with illustrator Pantones are still there.

Comment: But you have destination set to CMYK, is that ok?

Comment: In this case yes because I intend to print it. So I use CMYK mode. Nevertheless this is the default setting I have not touched it. Just checked if Pantones were  still there and they are indeed.

Comment: verify after exporting your PDF. So export and then drag the file to illustrator again and see if pantones are still there.  They should be :)
The only reason it shows "(modified)" is because I edited marks and bleeds when exported. But that has nothing to do with the colour settings on the document.

Comment: Ok and how about colours - are they still the same after conversion, they did not change? I made two versions, one without conversion and second with, the PDF without conversion looks much closer to the Pantone that is in the file.

Comment: The ones I have been exporting with those settings I showed you look more like the file I am working on. With no conversion it looks like the pantone goes brighter. Do you have your file set as CMYK before you export it?

Comment: Still if you have a pantone code when you send it to a printer they should respect the pantone and not just use the file you send as it is because it will depend on the printer and the printing process. But this is a separate issue.

If you are worried about the colour changing I would just advise to export it as it is and make sure you worked in CMYK and exported CMYK. Then advise the printer to look at the pantones on your file and respect them even if that means running some colour tests.